# Does Stack Overflow deliberately show more job ads to me when I'm browsing from work?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed I hardly ever get ads for jobs when I'm working on my laptop at home.

But all day at work I get a ton of ads for really high paying jobs.

My employer hired me via Stack Overflow using the IP address that I'm now working from.

*Possible conspiracy: so when managers walk by and see me getting ads for jobs that pay a lot more they have positive reinforcement on having hired me using the site*

Or maybe added benefit of co-workers also seeing ads, so single ad becomes worth more. Thus show more ads at work and counteract showing a lot of ads by showing less somewhere else?

*Note: I did use to see a lot of ads at home, before I started this job.*

*Note: I'm also not upset in anyway if anything it benefits me.*

Comment: That's unlikely a conspiracy but is more likely based on your browser history. At work you probably view more work related things.

Comment: I never look at work related things at work. That's too much work.

Comment: @EliSadoff I'm joking about that part. I'm just curious as to how ad targeting works. Always assumed it would be based on account, not computer, or IP address.

Comment: @EliSadoff are you saying SO can see what I browse outside of their own network to tell that I use YouTube more at home than at work? I don't think it's possible for a website to scrape your history that would be a security breach.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride SO's ads engage in some form of targeting. I'm not 100% positive as to how they do that, but they advertise themselves as doing such [here](https://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise).

Comment: It's likely to be an IP-based coincidence: they are probably able to location-match your work IP to more jobs nearby than your home IP, for whatever reason. (I guess in theory, they could be displaying more ads during the U.S. standard workday, but not sure that would actually make sense... personally I'd suspect the *opposite,* that job ads seen outside of work are much more effective, if just because there's less hesitation to open the ad.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 maybe but it wouldn't be location because I live 2 blocks from work on the same street.

Comment: @Philip not every IP address can be geolocated with the same accuracy. Depends on the provider

Comment: Alternate title: "Are you people trying to get me fired?!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Note: In this answer I'm specifically referring to *job ads only*.)

To be completely transparent here: The system has pretty much no idea of the concept of "your work/office" as opposed to "not your work/office". We just care about your given location at the time of the impression.

If you're using the same account at both locations, then the only differentiating factor will be the location itself. There may just be more high paying jobs closer to your current work location than there are near your home.

> I guess in theory, they could be displaying more ads during the U.S. standard workday

We don't do this intentionally, but we *do* get more traffic during the weekday than the weekends, so technically we serve more ads on weekdays as a result.

> Always assumed it would be based on account, not computer, or IP address

Generally it is. Our targeting is based on your Stack Overflow browsing history. If you're not logged in, we use a cookie to keep track of what you're looking at. Kevin's [blog post](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) goes into a lot more detail about how we do that.

Your IP address is *solely* used for getting an idea of *where* you are (GeoIP data).

Basically, what we do is try to come up with a number that represents our idea of how likely you are to click on a given job ad. The factors that go into coming up with that number are:

- Your Providence profile
- Your job matching preferences
- The targeting information the employer has assigned to the job
- Your location (based on your IP)
- The job's location
- What jobs you've already seen
- What jobs you've already applied to

All those things go into calculating that final score for a given job. We then use that score and a bit of randomness to pick N jobs (2 or 4 depending on the size of the ad) and then show those to you.

One of the things on our roadmap is to put this information up somewhere publicly accessible (and easily discoverable) with more detail. We strongly believe in being open first and foremost, and realize that the *job ad* portion of Stack Overflow is a bit of a black box (or in this case, blue or orange). We're not entirely certain when we'll be able to get to it, but we will!

Comment: 1) Stats 2) Magic 3) ??? 4) Profit

Comment: Interesting everyone mentions location but I live and work in middle of nowhere Canada and gets ads for jobs mostly in the USA. I'm going to research IP based geotagging and compare the results of my house to work both only separated by two blocks. If anything

Comment: Another explanation I'm considering based on your answer. Is that for some reason despite being logged in I was being served ads based on cookie and not account. The reason I say this is that I remember having an incognito window for cache reasons and seeing the exact same very high paying jobs as I did in my normal window.

Comment: We use MaxMind's database for our GeoIP lookups. You can check [here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo) to get a result that's more in line with what we'd get for a job ad request.